# What's the meaning of 私だけなのが?

Tags: translation, meaning

In the story I'm reading, a girl is given a gift from her boyfriend, after which she says,

> 「それをもらったの…**私だけなの**が幸せなのです…」

I'm at a complete loss as to how to parse this.「私だけなの」is happy? "Only I am happy"? Somehow I find that interpretation unlikely, as the boyfriend isn't popular and the girl isn't the jealous type.

Could someone shed some light on this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> 「それをもらったの…私だけなの」が、幸せなのです…
> →「それをもらったの**は**私だけである(という)こと」が、幸せなのです。
>
> (literally) Happiness is that it was only me who received it.
> What is happy is that I am the only person who received it (from the boy).

The second の before が is a nominalizer. The part in the brackets is a cleft-sentence, but は (or が) is replaced by an ellipsis (presumably because she is a taciturn character).

Comment: Would it be possible to omit なの completely from the original line and say 「それをもらったの…私だけが、幸せなのです…」?

Comment: @lightweaver No, that would change the meaning of the sentence. This sentence says "The happy thing is the fact that only I received it", rather than "Only I am happy (and everybody else is unhappy)".

Comment: Hmm I see. So なの can nominalize entire clauses as ということ can?

Comment: Yes, for example 彼が有名人なのを知らなかった and 明日が休みなのは嬉しい. This な is the attributive form of the copula だ.